How to fetch changes in part of a git repo under a different directory structure not under main repo directory (and even on another file system)
I'm using termux and using git to backup configurations within the termux home directory and in the shared directory (which is on a different filesystem, which I can't avoid the way termux is setup).
I had no problems until changing a file manally on github, and then trying to pull that change to my local branch. I'm getting both directory structures onto github as below
echo "Commit message:"

read -r commit_message
echo "$commit_message"
echo "Working..."
git add -A
git --work-tree=/ add  /storage/emulated/0/termux -A
#git status | less
git commit -m "$commit_message"
git push origin

If I change a file on github under /storage/emulated/0/termux, a git pull doesnt see it there, but it does under the main work-tree no problem.
Short of making /storage/emulated/0/termux a submodule and thus a completely different repo, is there a way do to a pull request to capture and pull down changes under /storage/emulated/0/termux?
Thank you for any help,
Nathan
